# WebStorm code completion for node.js, express and EJS

Tags: node.js, express, intellisense, webstorm, ejs

I'm learning node.js just now and am using WebStorm 7.0.2 to edit the code (I use this IDE on a daily basis for my other hmlt5 + JS work, but apparently don't know it as much as I'd thought :-)).

What I don't know yet is how to include additional modules in my project so that WebStorm sees them and provide code completion - I've got an issue with EJS - in the template files there're no suggestions and all the keywords are seen by WebStorm as unresolved. I've got similar issue with Express framework as a whole - functions like get/post/bodyParser are not recognized.

Somehow I managed to introduce a directory "node_modules/express" into my project but I have no idea how I did it - I've followed some example from google possibly..?

Can anyone kindly enlighten me what has to be done for WebStorm to see what's needed? I have Node.js Core Modules checked in my JavaScript->Libraries panel...

Thank you in advance for pointing me in a good direction.
Piotr

Answer (score 11):

WebStorm suggests you to mark modules from your project's node_modules directory as external libraries automatically on the project start. You can also add modules manually in JavaScript | Libraries -> Add to get code completion for them.

There are some issues with code completion for Express framework. I suggest to download  TypeScript definition files (Preferences: JavaScript | Libraries -> Download | TypeScript Community Stubs -> Express) to get proper completion for it.

Try having .ejs file type when you work with EJS templates.